# How to extend mysqli_result and add new method

Tags: php, inheritance, mysqli, resultset

Mysqli_result class has `fetch_all()` method returning multiple rows from result set at once in form of an array of rows (actually that's 2-dimensional array because rows already are arrays of fields). Also a result set has method `fetch_object()` returning a single row in form of an object.

Now I'd like to extend mysqli_result class and add new method `fetch_objects()` (plural) which would return an associative array of objects where association key is record ID [id=>Object()]. Of course, I'll need to extend mysqli class too and override its query() method in order to return my extended result set. But I don't get how the transfer of connection and query parameter between mysqli and returned mysqli_result is made.

This should work this way:

```
$db=new ReallyMySQLi(...); //initiating my mysqli

$myrst=$db->query($SQL); //returned my extended result

//fetch_objects() returning associative array of objects
//with record ID as associative key
foreach($myrst->fetch_objects() as $id=>$object)
{
  echo 'Customer ID:'.$id; //or $object->id;
  echo 'Customer firstname:'.$object->firstname;
  echo 'Customer lastname:'.$object->lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on the PHP manual of [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#88062) and tinkered some. I didn't try though.

```
class Database_MySQLi extends MySQLi
{
    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->real_query($query);
        return new Database_MySQLi_Result($this);
    }
}

class Database_MySQLi_Result extends MySQLi_Result
{
    public function fetch_objects()
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $this->fetch_object())
        {
            $rows[$row->id] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

And the usage would be

```
$db=new Database_MySQLi(...); //initiating my mysqli

$myrst=$db->query($SQL); //returned my extended result

//fetch_objects() returning associative array of objects
//with record ID as associative key
foreach($myrst->fetch_objects() as $id=>$object)
{
  echo 'Customer ID:'.$id; //or $object->id;
  echo 'Customer firstname:'.$object->firstname;
  echo 'Customer lastname:'.$object->lastname;
}
```

Comment: Shame on me I really don't know how I didn't find this note (althoufg spent some time in searching). However, I tested this code it and it works!!! But I still don't get how it does work!!! What instruction `$this->real_query($query)` inside Database_MySQLi does!? Also, when mysqli issues `return new Database_MySQLi_result($this)` it instanciates extended mysqli_result and sends itself as an argument to result, but constructor of result does not have parameters! I'm still confused!

Comment: I don't know about the real_query either. I was just passing by and done a small research and saw this. Just thought I could share. God save the public but undocumented variables & methods! maybe he just `var_dump`ed the mysqli_result class and found out these.

Comment: The usage of `real_query()` instead of `query()` method is crucial here! I tested, this code **does not** work with `$this->query($query)`. real_query executes query and leaves result in database (unbuffered result - storing only pointer to it in mysqli) and this result should be used or stored afterwards.

Comment: Yes, and it was documented too.. http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.real-query.php. Missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I never use mysqli as mysql driver two years. But i make this recommendation for you.

You can choose PDO, PDO is so cool as multipile database driver.

Like laravel eloquent, doctrine both use PDO as foundation.

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Good luck!